# Scrapy errors when using -t csv -o data.csv

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I have my scrapy bot running on two different systems. One of them is working properly while the other one isn't. They're identical copies. When I use -t csv -o data.csv, I get the following traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/scraper/.python/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
    execute()
  File "/home/scraper/.python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 143, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/home/scraper/.python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 89, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/scraper/.python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/home/scraper/.python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 50, in run
    self.crawler_process.start()
  File "/home/scraper/.python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 92, in start
    if self.start_crawling():
  File "/home/scraper/.python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 124, in start_crawling
    return self._start_crawler() is not None
  File "/home/scraper/.python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 139, in _start_crawler
    crawler.configure()
  File "/home/scraper/.python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 46, in configure
    self.extensions = ExtensionManager.from_crawler(self)
  File "/home/scraper/.python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 50, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/home/scraper/.python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 31, in from_settings
    mw = mwcls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/home/scraper/.python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/feedexport.py", line 162, in from_crawler
    o = cls(crawler.settings)
  File "/home/scraper/.python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/feedexport.py", line 144, in __init__
    if not self._storage_supported(self.urifmt):
  File "/home/scraper/.python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/feedexport.py", line 214, in _storage_supported
    self._get_storage(uri)
  File "/home/scraper/.python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/feedexport.py", line 225, in _get_storage
    return self.storages[urlparse(uri).scheme](uri)
  File "/home/scraper/.python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/feedexport.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.path = file_uri_to_path(uri)
  File "/home/scraper/.python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/w3lib/url.py", line 141, in file_uri_to_path
    uri_path = moves.urllib.parse.urlparse(uri).path
AttributeError: 'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse' object has no attribute 'urlparse'
```

Comment: Please paste your spider's code

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `six` module is not the required by `w3lib`.

Try:

```
     pip install -U w3lib six
```